# Using substring() in a jQuery array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I use a filter function in jQuery (for a research bar in a dropdown).

It filters everything between `<h1>` tags in my HTML code below and I want it filters only the text between `<span>` tag. (azerty1 in this example)

**Javascript**

```
function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, div, h1, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    /*Catch everything between tags <h1> and </h1>*/
    h1 = div.getElementsByTagName("h1");

    for (i = 0; i < h1.length; i++)
    {
        if (h1[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
        {
            h1[i].style.display = "";
        }
        /*No resultat = display nothing*/
        else
        {
            h1[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    } }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button  class="buttonMe"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <!--Filter bar-->
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Blablabla 1</li>
        <li>
          <h1><img src="images/dropdown/1.png"><span>azerty1</span></h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example when I filter with A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye7Ij.png)

it shows me everything because it starts from img src="im**a**ges/...

[Example when I filter with AZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6GCT.png)

it shows me the right things because only **az**erty1 starts with AZ

I don't know what to use between a substring and ignoring first child (`img` tag), and how to use them, and where to place those codes in my javascript (probably in the for loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read the contents of the span tag by using `h1[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML` instead of `h1[i].innerHTML`

```js
function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, div, h1, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    /*Catch everything between tags <h1> and </h1>*/
    h1 = div.getElementsByTagName("h1");

    for (i = 0; i < h1.length; i++)
    {
        if (h1[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
        {
            h1[i].style.display = "";
        }
        /*No resultat = display nothing*/
        else
        {
            h1[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    } }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button  class="buttonMe"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <!--Filter bar-->
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Blablabla 1</li>
        <li>
          <h1><img src="images/dropdown/1.png"><span>azerty1</span></h1>
          <h1><img src="images/dropdown/2.png"><span>test</span></h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```